# Передвижение элементов в react-grid-layout

Tags: reactjs, рекурсия, react-grid-layout

Я пишу проект на React, в котором использую react-grid-layout. Я создаю несколько сеток внутри друг друга с помощью рекурсии. Компонент имеет такой вид:

```
export default function CustomLayout({ layout, onDragStart, onDragStop }) {
  const [isDraggable, setIsDraggable] = React.useState(true);

  return (
    <GridLayout
      className="layout"
      onDragStart={onDragStart}
      onDragStop={onDragStop}
      layout={layout}
      cols={24}
      rowHeight={80}
      width={1600}
      isDraggable={isDraggable}
    >
      {layout.map((item) => {
        if (item.children) {
          return (
            <div
              onClick={(e) => console.log(e.currentTarget.textContent[0])}
              key={item.i}
              style={{ background: "pink", border: "1px solid black" }}
            >
              <CustomLayout
                layout={item.children}
                onDragStart={() => {
                  setIsDraggable(false);
                }}
                onDragStop={() => {
                  setIsDraggable(true);
                }}
              />
            </div>
          );
        } else {
          return (
            <div
              key={item.i}
              style={{ background: "purple" }}
            >
              {item.i}
            </div>
          );
        }
      })}
    </GridLayout>
  );
}
```

Я смог добавить функционал того, чтобы элементы на дочерних сетках можно было перетаскивать (с помощью [isDraggable, setIsDraggable]), но проблема в следующем: если я переместил элемент на сетке третьего уровня, то не смогу переместить элемент на главной сетке, пока не перемещу элемент на сетке второго уровня. Как можно поправить такое поведение? 
P.S. если нужна ссылка на codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-tree-z2w5nn?file=/src/gridLayout.js:179-1433